# Remove sidebar in Twenty Seventeen from single products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I have been trying to figure out how to remove the shop sidebar from my single product pages. I have tried various options for this.  I am using the twentyseventeen theme.
I first tried this snippet from business bloomer in my child functions file.

```
 add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_remove_sidebar_product_pages' );
 
function bbloomer_remove_sidebar_product_pages() {
if ( is_product() ) {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
}
}
```

But this did not work.Subsequently read a thread from another user saying that snippet did not work for twentyseventeen theme.

I then tried to override the woo commerce template woocommerce/templates/singleproduct.php by creating woocommerce/singleproduct.php in my child theme and removing the following:

```
 <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

This did not work either. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

For the Twenty Seventeen theme, there is a special class in Woocommerce [`WC_Twenty_Seventeen`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Twenty_Seventeen.html) that handle the sidebar.

So use the following to remove the sidebar from single product pages:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', array( 'WC_Twenty_Seventeen', 'output_content_wrapper_end' ), 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'remove_sidebar_from_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );
function remove_sidebar_from_output_content_wrapper_end() {
    // Only for single product pages
    if( is_product() ) {
        echo '</main></div></div>';
    } else {
        echo '</main></div>';
        get_sidebar();
        echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

But you will have to add some CSS rules to your `styles.css` file, something like:

```
.has-sidebar.single-product.woocommerce-page:not(.error404) #primary {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi again LoicTheAztec, I have just realised that this has not worked for me.  But has simply pushed the sidebar content down beneath the main page content.  It does this with or without the css change to the sidebar width. I wonder if it makes a difference because the shop sidebar is a custom sidebar that i created and pulled into sidebar.php as a conditional tag (following coding I think you kindly gave me a few weeks ago!).  Would this make a difference?

Comment: Here is a link to a product page so you can see what I mean.https://www.walsinghamgalleryandframing.co.uk/development/?product=hogging-the-hedge

Comment: @SusanNeil This code works for a normal Twenty Seventeen theme with Woocommerce. I can't handle any custom customization that are interacting with it.

Comment: ok fair enough.  I have removed the sidebar with css display:none.  Thanks for your  help